# how to play vimeo video using iframe in webview?

Tags: android, iframe, android-webview, vimeo

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        // how plugin is enabled change in API 8
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
          wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        } else {
          wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        }
        String venkat="<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/27244727?portrait=0&color=333\" width=\"WIDTH\" height=\"HEIGHT\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>";
        wv.loadData(venkat,"text/html","UTF-8");
    }
}
```

After researching from google I have written the above code but is not working. In this no errors are occurred but when I click on the play button progress bar is displaying for sometime and then it disappears and displays play button again... Could anyone please suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" 
        width="515" 
        height="340" 
        frameborder="0" 
        webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: how to enable autoplay

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the hardware accelaration feature in andorid manifest. To work vimeo video on all devices, bec vimeo video is html5 type of video.

And [here is  link of vimeo video play](https://github.com/bilthon/VimeoTest) which is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const TheVideo = (props) => {
 const getVimeoUrl = (uri: string): string => {
        const value = uri.split("/");
        return value[value.length - 1];
    };
    enter code here

return (<>
 <iframe
                        src={
                            props.specificVideo?.url
                                ?.split("/")[2]
                                .startsWith("vimeo")
                                ? `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${getVimeoUrl(
                                      props.specificVideo?.url
                                  )}`
                                : props.specificVideo?.url ?? ""
                        }
                        width="{video_width}"
                        height="{video_height}"
                        frameBorder="0"
                        title={props.specificVideo?.title ?? ""}
                        className="specvideoview-frame"
                    ></iframe>
</>)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.presentation_webview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        Log.e("h & w",wwidth+"-"+height);

        String data_html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\" xmlns:fb=\"http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\"> <head></head> <body style=\"margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe width='"+wwidth+"' height='"+height+"' src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+VIDEO_ID+"\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> </body> </html> ";

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://vimeo.com", data_html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Try the above code and use device width and height to play the video.