# play all types videos in webview in android programmatically

Tags: android, webview, yahoo-api, android-youtube-api, vimeo-api

I want to play All types videos in single webview in android programmatically.

I already tried for yahoo/youtube/vimeo videos play in webview in android using iframe.
But, its not working properly.

only working for youtube videos only playing in webview using iframe in android.

next one, vimeo video is playing in webview, but, its not playing full video, just loading video in webview,
that's it. its not fully playing.Its automatically paused. 
when I click play button, its again paused..

next one, yahoo video is not playing fully..

I refereed those link also.
[how to play vimeo video using iframe in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895437/how-to-play-vimeo-video-using-iframe-in-webview)
https://github.com/droid28/VimeoVideo
[Auto playing vimeo videos in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030524/auto-playing-vimeo-videos-in-android-webview)

also I put some questions related this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402410/play-vimeo-videos-in-webview-in-android-programmatically
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402052/play-yahoo-videos-in-webview-in-android-programmatically

can anyone help me to come out from this problem.

Thanks
Advance