# Playing iframe videos in android 4.2.2

Tags: android, iframe, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Did anyone have problems playing videos embedded in webview using iframe on android 4.2.2, everything works fine on 4.4+ but on 4.2 videos won't play.

This is how data is loaded

```
String content = "<iframe allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"270\" src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x22rv5x\" width=\"480\"></iframe>"
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadData(content, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

You can try adding any youtube links too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to play vimeo video using iframe in webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895437/how-to-play-vimeo-video-using-iframe-in-webview)

Comment: @maveň this is working, thnx

Comment: That is something cool, Glad to help :)